# How to use TCP in Racket?

Tags: tcp, scheme, racket

I was trying to send a message from a client to a server, and print the message on the server.

**server.rkt:**

```
#lang racket
(define the-listener (tcp-listen 9876))
(define-values (in out) (tcp-accept the-listener))
(displayln (read in))
(tcp-close the-listener)
```

**client.rkt:**

```
#lang racket
(define-values (in out) (tcp-connect "localhost" 9876))
(write "Hello" out)
```

I ran `server.rkt` and then `client.rkt` in the terminal. But the server only prints `#<eof>` instead of the `Hello` message.

Why is that? And how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flush the output on the client side with [`flush-output`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-buffers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._flush-output%29%29) after sending the message. 
Don't forget to cleanly close the ports with `close-input-port` and `close-output-port` after usage too, on both the client and the server.

**Edit:** To answer the first part of your question, you get `#<eof>` because your client finishes before its output port has been flushed, which closes this output port, and therefore the server receives this end-of-file message (but means "end-of-stream" rather, here), which you can test with [`eof-object?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eof-object~3f%29%29).

Comment: Thanks, Metaxal. How did you learn about these? I read the docs and searched the internet, but found nothing until your answer.

Comment: I learned this some time ago by trial and error and looking at the docs, possibly with help of the Racket mailing list. You can find some other relevant info [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/concurrency.html) too.