# Running a Scheme or Racket interpreter in the background to run scripts

Tags: scheme, racket, interpreter

I'd like to know how it is possible to run a Scheme or Racket interpreter in the background (like a daemon) to send scripts to it and obtain the results.

This is like the mechanism applied to make interfaces like [Jupyter notebooks](https://jupyter.org) or Emacs' [Racket-mode](https://racket-mode.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open a network connection in order to connect the read-eval-print-loop to the connection. See [here](https://wiki.call-cc.org/Connecting%20to%20a%20REPL%20via%20sockets) for an Chicken-Scheme example.

> ```
> (import (chicken tcp))
>
> (define (remote-repl #!optional (port 9999))
>   (let*-values (((x) (tcp-listen port))
>                 ((i o) (tcp-accept x)))
>     (current-input-port i)
>     (current-output-port o)
>     (current-error-port o) 
>     (repl)))
>
> (remote-repl)
> ```

But you do not need to write this yourself. Just use a [TCP wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrappers).

Comment: The same works for Racket?

Comment: Could you also add the client-side code, where the command is sent to the server?

Comment: [How to use TCP in Racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598836/how-to-use-tcp-in-racket)